# Angular display image in new tab

Tags: html, angular, image

I have a carousel image viewer on my page I want the user when clicks on an Image it opens up that Image in a browser new tab, I wrote the code below but it downloads the image instead of displaying it.

component.ts:

```
    openFile(url: string) {
    window.open(url, "_blank");
}
```

component.html

```
<ss-lightslider-slide *ngFor="let image of images"
                        [attr.data-thumb]="image.value"
                        [attr.data-src]="image.value"
                        [attr.data-id]="image.id"
                        class="ss-asset-thumbnail">
        <img [src]="image.value" class="d-block w-100" title="{{image.name}}" alt="{{image.name}}" (click)="openFile(image.value)"/>
</ss-lightslider-slide>
```

how can I make it that on `<img>` tag when its clicked it display the image instead of downloading it?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a  window service  and when clicked on Image write something like

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class WindRefService {
  constructor() {}
  getNativeWindow() {
    return window;
  }
}
```

```
 onView() {
      this.nativeWindow.open(image);
    
  }
```

You might have to look for `getNativeWindow()` to use for your case

Comment: `WindRefService` isn't a thing in Angular

Comment: Sorry, I meant to create a window service. I just updated it.

Comment: I don't understand your answer can you explain more?